# Redundant blank lines after regex_match()

Tags: c++, regex

I'm doing my miniSQL and trying to use regular expression to parse the user input.

I failed to handle the case 'create table myTable(c char(20))'. As show below, the second and the thrid lines are unwanted. I'm just wondering why they would appear in the result.
[image]

Here is my code:

```
void onCreateTable(const smatch& cmd);

int main()
{
    std::string cmd = " create table a(c char(20))";
    regex pattern;
    smatch result;
    pattern = regex("\\s*create\\s+table\\s+(\\w+)\\s*\\((.*)\\)\\s*", regex::icase);
    if  ( regex_match(cmd, result, pattern) )
    {
        onCreateTable( result );
    }

    int x; cin >> x;
    return 0;
}

void onCreateTable( const smatch& cmd )
{
    cout << "onCreateTable" << endl;
    string tableName = cmd[1];
    string attr = cmd[2];
    regex pattern = regex("\\s*(\\w+\\s+int)|(\\w+\\s+float)|(\\w+\\s+char\\(\\d+\\))",     regex::icase);
    // which will print redundant blank lines

    // while the below one will print the exact result 
    // regex pattern = regex("\\s*(\\w+\\s+char\\(\\d+\\))", regex::icase);
    smatch result;
    if ( regex_match(attr, result, pattern) )
    {
        cout << "match!"  << endl;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < result.size(); i ++)
        {
            cout << result[i] << endl;
        }
    } else
    {
        cout << "A table must have at least 1 column." << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like it's recording a group for all three of your parenthesized expressions, but obviously only one of them actually matches, so it's printing the first two as blanks. What happens if you wrap the entire expression after `\\s*` in an additional pair of parentheses? If you change the order so the group with `char` in it comes before the other two, do you then get two blank lines at the end, rather than in the middle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last regex has 3 capture groups separated by alternations.
Only 1 will match. You're sitting in a loop printing all of the smatch array.
The smatch array is the size of all your capture groups.

```
      \s* 
 1    ( \w+ \s+ int )
   |  
 2    ( \w+ \s+ float )
   |  
 3    ( \w+ \s+ char\( \d+ \) )
```

Group 0 is the whole match.
Group 1 didn't match, its empty.
Group 2 didn't match, its empty.
Group 3 matchd.

You probably want to check if a group matched.
Something like if (`result[i].matched`) { }
Or whatever flag smatch uses.